# Extract fundamental data with interactive broker from specific tags in python 3

Tags: xml, python-3.x, interactive-brokers

all. I want to extract the specific fundamental data from Interactive Broker API (Python 3), however, it shows the xml version. I can't get for example Market capitalization (by ' print(callback.fundamental_Data_data.find("MKTCAP"))')

```
import pandas as pd
import time
from IBWrapper import IBWrapper, contract
from ib.ext.EClientSocket import EClientSocket
from ib.ext.ScannerSubscription import ScannerSubscription
import re


stocks=[
'5'
]

for x in stocks:
    callback = IBWrapper()             
    tws = EClientSocket(callback)      
    host = "127.0.0.1"
    port = 7496
    clientId = 25
    tws.eConnect(host, port, clientId) 
    create = contract()                
    callback.initiate_variables()
    contract_Details = create.create_contract(x, 'STK', 'SEHK', 'HKD')
    tickerId = 8001

    tws.reqFundamentalData(tickerId, 
                      contract_Details,
                      "ReportSnapshot"
                      )
    time.sleep(5)

    print(callback.fundamental_Data_data)
    print(callback.fundamental_Data_data.find("AATCA")) 
    print(callback.fundamental_Data_data.find("ACFSHR"))
    print(callback.fundamental_Data_data.find("ADIV5YAVG"))
    print(callback.fundamental_Data_data.find("MKTCAP"))
    print(callback.fundamental_Data_data.find("QTANBVPS"))
    print(callback.fundamental_Data_data.find("REVCHNGYR"))
    print(callback.fundamental_Data_data.find("REVTRENDGR"))
    tws.eDisconnect()
    time.sleep(5) 

tws.eDisconnect()
```

Output:
It is all in xml format, most fundamental data can be shown.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <RepportSnapshot Major="1" Minor="0" Revision="1">
    <CoIDs>
            <CoID Type="RepNo">AC317</CoID>
            <CoID Type="CompanyName">HSBC Holdings plc (Hong Kong)</CoID>
    </CoIDs>
    <Issues>
            <Issue ID="1" Type="C" Desc="Common Stock" Order="1">
                    <IssueID Type="Name">Ordinary Shares</IssueID>
                    <IssueID Type="Ticker">5</IssueID>
                    <IssueID Type="CUSIP">G4634U169</IssueID>
                    <IssueID Type="ISIN">GB0005405286</IssueID>
                    <IssueID Type="RIC">0005.HK</IssueID>
                    <IssueID Type="SEDOL">6158163</IssueID>
                    <IssueID Type="DisplayRIC">0005.HK</IssueID>
                    <IssueID Type="InstrumentPI">312270</IssueID>
                    <IssueID Type="QuotePI">1049324</IssueID>
                    <Exchange Code="HKG" Country="HKG">Hong Kong Stock                     
Exchange</Exchange>
                    <MostRecentSplit Date="2009-03- 
12">1.14753</MostRecentSplit>
            </Issue>
    </Issues>
    <CoGeneralInfo>
            <CoStatus Code="1">Active</CoStatus>
            <CoType Code="EQU">Equity Issue</CoType>
            <LastModified>2018-07-20</LastModified>
            <LatestAvailableAnnual>2017-12-31</LatestAvailableAnnual>
            <LatestAvailableInterim>2018-03-31</LatestAvailableInterim>
            <Employees LastUpdated="2018-03-31">228899</Employees>
            <SharesOut Date="2018-07-24" 
 TotalFloat="19882952713.0">19952507521.0</SharesOut>
            <ReportingCurrency Code="USD">U.S. Dollars</ReportingCurrency>
            <MostRecentExchange Date="2018-07-24">1.0</MostRecentExchange>
    </CoGeneralInfo>
    <TextInfo>
            <Text Type="Business Summary" lastModified="2017-03- 
 06T22:03:17">HSBC Holdings plc (HSBC) is the banking and financial services 
 company. The Company manages its products and services through four     
 businesses: Retail Banking and Wealth Management (RBWM), Commercial Banking 
 (CMB), Global Banking and Markets (GB&amp;M), and Global Private Banking 
 (GPB). It operates across various geographical regions, which include 
 Europe, Asia, Middle East and North Africa, North America and Latin America. 
 RBWM business offers Retail Banking, Wealth Management, Asset Management and 
 Insurance. CMB services include working capital, term loans, payment 
 services and international trade facilitation, among other services, as well 
 as expertise in mergers and acquisitions, and access to financial markets. 
 GB&amp;M supports government, corporate and institutional clients across the 
 world. GPB's products and services include Investment Management, Private 
 Wealth Solutions, and a range of Private Banking services.</Text>
            <Text Type="Financial Summary" lastModified="2018-07- 
20T09:20:11">BRIEF: For the three months ended 31 March 2018, HSBC Holdings 
plc (Hong Kong) interest income increased 10% to $7.46B. Net interest income 
after loan loss provision increased 11% to $7.29B.  Net income applicable to 
common stockholders decreased 1% to $3.09B. Net interest income after loan 
loss provision reflects Asia segment increase of 22% to $3.86B, Net Interest 
Margin, Total -% increase of 2% to 1.67%, Net Interest Spread.</Text>
    </TextInfo>
    <contactInfo lastUpdated="2018-07-20T09:20:26">
            <streetAddress line="1">8 Canada Square</streetAddress>
            <streetAddress line="2"></streetAddress>
            <streetAddress line="3"></streetAddress>
            <city>LONDON</city>
            <state-region></state-region>
            <postalCode>E14 5HQ</postalCode>
            <country code="GBR">United Kingdom</country>
            <contactName></contactName>
            <contactTitle></contactTitle>
            <phone>
                    <phone type="mainphone">
                            <countryPhoneCode>44</countryPhoneCode>
                            <city-areacode>20</city-areacode>
                            <number>79918888</number>
                    </phone>
                    <phone type="mainfax">
                            <countryPhoneCode>44</countryPhoneCode>
                            <city-areacode>20</city-areacode>
                            <number>79924880</number>
                    </phone>
            </phone>
    </contactInfo>
    <webLinks lastUpdated="2016-11-07T05:00:04"><webSite mainCategory="Home 
 Page">http://www.hsbc.com/</webSite><eMail mainCategory="Company Contact/E- 
 mail"></eMail></webLinks>
    <peerInfo lastUpdated="2018-07-20T09:20:26">
            <IndustryInfo>
                    <Industry type="TRBC" order="1" reported="0" 
 code="5510101010" mnem="">Banks - NEC</Industry>
                    <Industry type="NAICS" order="1" reported="0" 
 code="52211" mnem="">Commercial Banking</Industry>
                    <Industry type="NAICS" order="2" reported="0" 
 code="52393" mnem="">Investment Advice</Industry>
                    <Industry type="NAICS" order="3" reported="0" 
 code="52392" mnem="">Portfolio Management</Industry>
                    <Industry type="SIC" order="0" reported="1" code="6035" 
 mnem="">Federal Savings Institutions</Industry>
                    <Industry type="SIC" order="1" reported="0" code="6029" 
 mnem="">Commercial Banks, Nec</Industry>
                    <Industry type="SIC" order="2" reported="0" code="6282" 
 mnem="">Investment Advice</Industry>
            </IndustryInfo>
    </peerInfo>
    <officers>
            <officer rank="1" since="01/01/2013">
                    <firstName>John</firstName>
                    <mI>Michael</mI>
                    <lastName>Flint</lastName>
                    <age>48 </age>
                    <title startYear="2018" startMonth="02" startDay="21" 
 iD1="CEO" abbr1="CEO" iD2="EDR" abbr2="Exec. Dir.">Chief Executive, 
 Executive Director</title>
            </officer>
            <officer rank="2" since="09/24/2010">
                    <firstName>Iain</firstName>
                    <mI>J.</mI>
                    <lastName>Mackay</lastName>
                    <age>56 </age>
                    <title startYear="2010" startMonth="12" startDay="03" 
  iD1="FID" abbr1="Fin. Dir." iD2="EDR" abbr2="Exec. Dir.">Group Finance 
  Director, Executive Director</title>
            </officer>
            <officer rank="3" since="08/01/2015">
                    <firstName>Andy</firstName>
                    <mI></mI>
                    <lastName>Maguire</lastName>
                    <age>51 </age>
                    <title startYear="2015" startMonth="08" startDay="01" 
  iD1="COO" abbr1="COO" iD2="MDR" abbr2="Mgng.Dir.">Group Chief Operating 
  Officer, Group Managing Director</title>
            </officer>
            <officer rank="4" since="11/26/2010">
                    <firstName>Marc</firstName>
                    <mI>M.</mI>
                    <lastName>Moses</lastName>
                    <age>60 </age>
                    <title startYear="2014" startMonth="01" startDay="01" 
  iD1="CRO" abbr1="CRO" iD2="EDR" abbr2="Exec. Dir.">Group Chief Risk 
  Officer, Executive Director</title>
            </officer>
            <officer rank="5" since="NA">
                    <firstName>Elaine</firstName>
                    <mI></mI>
                    <lastName>Arden</lastName>
                    <age>49 </age>
                    <title startYear="NA" startMonth="" startDay="" iD1="MDR" 
 abbr1="Mgng.Dir." iD2="" abbr2="">Managing Director, Group Head of Human 
 Resources</title>
            </officer>
            <officer rank="6" since="01/01/2011">
                    <firstName>Samir</firstName>
                    <mI></mI>
                    <lastName>Assaf</lastName>
                    <age>57 </age>
                    <title startYear="2011" startMonth="01" startDay="01" 
  iD1="MDR" abbr1="Mgng.Dir." iD2="" abbr2="">Group Managing Director, Chief 
  Executive - Global Banking &amp; Markets</title>
            </officer>
            <officer rank="7" since="NA">
                    <firstName>Colin</firstName>
                    <mI></mI>
                    <lastName>Bell</lastName>
                    <age>50 </age>
                    <title startYear="NA" startMonth="" startDay="" iD1="MDR" 
  abbr1="Mgng.Dir." iD2="" abbr2="">Managing Director, Group Head of 
  Financial Crime Risk</title>
            </officer>
            <officer rank="8" since="10/01/2013">
                    <firstName>Peter</firstName>
                    <mI>W.</mI>
                    <lastName>Boyles</lastName>
                    <age>62 </age>
                    <title startYear="2013" startMonth="10" startDay="01" 
   iD1="MDR" abbr1="Mgng.Dir." iD2="" abbr2="">Group Managing Director; Chief 
   Executive of Global Private Banking</title>
            </officer>
            <officer rank="9" since="08/01/2015">
                    <firstName>Patrick</firstName>
                    <mI>J.</mI>
                    <lastName>Burke</lastName>
                    <age>56 </age>
                    <title startYear="2015" startMonth="08" startDay="01" 
  iD1="MDR" abbr1="Mgng.Dir." iD2="" abbr2="">Group Managing Director; 
  President and Chief Executive of HSBC USA</title>
            </officer>
            <officer rank="10" since="08/01/2015">
                    <firstName>Pierre</firstName>
                    <mI></mI>
                    <lastName>Goad</lastName>
                    <age>56 </age>
                    <title startYear="2016" startMonth="" startDay="" 
  iD1="MDR" abbr1="Mgng.Dir." iD2="" abbr2="">Group Managing Director, Group 
  Head of Employee Insight and Communications</title>
            </officer>
    </officers>
    <Ratios PriceCurrency="HKD" ReportingCurrency="USD" 
  ExchangeRate="7.84640" LatestAvailableDate="2017-12-31">
            <Group ID="Price and Volume">
                    <Ratio FieldName="NPRICE" Type="N">75.05000</Ratio>
                    <Ratio FieldName="NHIG" Type="N">86.00000</Ratio>
                    <Ratio FieldName="NLOW" Type="N">71.45000</Ratio>
                    <Ratio FieldName="PDATE" Type="D">2018-07- 
  25T00:00:00</Ratio>
                    <Ratio FieldName="VOL10DAVG" Type="N">12.50806</Ratio>
                    <Ratio FieldName="EV" Type="N">2466752.00000</Ratio>
            </Group>
            <Group ID="Income Statement">
                    <Ratio FieldName="MKTCAP" Type="N">1505191.00000</Ratio>
                    <Ratio FieldName="AREV" Type="N">321663.20000</Ratio>
                    <Ratio FieldName="AEBITD" Type="N">177752.30000</Ratio>
                    <Ratio FieldName="ANIAC" Type="N">86082.85000</Ratio>
            </Group>
            <Group ID="Per share data">
                    <Ratio FieldName="AEPSXCLXOR" Type="N">4.28869</Ratio>
                    <Ratio FieldName="AREVPS" Type="N">27.04842</Ratio>
                    <Ratio FieldName="ABVPS" Type="N">74.66691</Ratio>
                    <Ratio FieldName="ACSHPS" Type="N">108.96660</Ratio>
                    <Ratio FieldName="ACFSHR" Type="N">5.83985</Ratio>
                    <Ratio FieldName="ADIVSHR" Type="N">4.01226</Ratio>
            </Group>
            <Group ID="Other Ratios">
                    <Ratio FieldName="AGROSMGN" Type="N">-99999.99000</Ratio>
                    <Ratio FieldName="AROEPCT" Type="N">6.72498</Ratio>
                    <Ratio FieldName="APR2REV" Type="N">2.77242</Ratio>
                    <Ratio FieldName="APEEXCLXOR" Type="N">17.49954</Ratio>
                    <Ratio FieldName="APRICE2BK" Type="N">1.13825</Ratio>
                    <Ratio FieldName="Employees" Type="N">228899</Ratio>
            </Group>
    </Ratios>
    <ForecastData ConsensusType="Mean" CurFiscalYear="2018" 
   CurFiscalYearEndMonth="12" CurInterimEndCalYear="2018" 
   CurInterimEndMonth="3" EarningsBasis="PRX">
            <Ratio FieldName="ConsRecom" Type="N">
                    <Value PeriodType="CURR">1.9167</Value>
            </Ratio>
            <Ratio FieldName="TargetPrice" Type="N">
                    <Value PeriodType="CURR">86.00753</Value>
            </Ratio>
            <Ratio FieldName="ProjLTGrowthRate" Type="N">
                    <Value PeriodType="CURR">6.9100</Value>
            </Ratio>
            <Ratio FieldName="ProjPE" Type="N">
                    <Value PeriodType="CURR">13.07573</Value>
            </Ratio>
            <Ratio FieldName="ProjSales" Type="N">
                    <Value PeriodType="CURR">433073.04033</Value>
            </Ratio>
            <Ratio FieldName="ProjSalesQ" Type="N">
                    <Value PeriodType="CURR">276091.27680</Value>
            </Ratio>
            <Ratio FieldName="ProjEPS" Type="N">
                    <Value PeriodType="CURR">5.73964</Value>
            </Ratio>
            <Ratio FieldName="ProjEPSQ" Type="N">
                    <Value PeriodType="CURR">1.64774</Value>
            </Ratio>
            <Ratio FieldName="ProjProfit" Type="N">
                    <Value PeriodType="CURR">168752.58051</Value>
            </Ratio>
            <Ratio FieldName="ProjDPS" Type="N">
                    <Value PeriodType="CURR">4.03148</Value>
            </Ratio>
    </ForecastData>
    </ReportSnapshot>

  -1
 8993
 -1
 8486
 -1
 -1
 -1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you get XML then use lxml or BeautifulSoup to get data from XML.

You can see `lxml` in use at the end of this code:

```
data = b'''<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <ReportSnapshot Major="1" Minor="0" Revision="1">
    <CoIDs>
            <CoID Type="RepNo">AC317</CoID>
            <CoID Type="CompanyName">HSBC Holdings plc (Hong Kong)</CoID>
    </CoIDs>
    <Issues>
            <Issue ID="1" Type="C" Desc="Common Stock" Order="1">
                    <IssueID Type="Name">Ordinary Shares</IssueID>
                    <IssueID Type="Ticker">5</IssueID>
                    <IssueID Type="CUSIP">G4634U169</IssueID>
                    <IssueID Type="ISIN">GB0005405286</IssueID>
                    <IssueID Type="RIC">0005.HK</IssueID>
                    <IssueID Type="SEDOL">6158163</IssueID>
                    <IssueID Type="DisplayRIC">0005.HK</IssueID>
                    <IssueID Type="InstrumentPI">312270</IssueID>
                    <IssueID Type="QuotePI">1049324</IssueID>
                    <Exchange Code="HKG" Country="HKG">Hong Kong Stock                     
Exchange</Exchange>
                    <MostRecentSplit Date="2009-03- 
12">1.14753</MostRecentSplit>
            </Issue>
    </Issues>
    <CoGeneralInfo>
            <CoStatus Code="1">Active</CoStatus>
            <CoType Code="EQU">Equity Issue</CoType>
            <LastModified>2018-07-20</LastModified>
            <LatestAvailableAnnual>2017-12-31</LatestAvailableAnnual>
            <LatestAvailableInterim>2018-03-31</LatestAvailableInterim>
            <Employees LastUpdated="2018-03-31">228899</Employees>
            <SharesOut Date="2018-07-24" 
 TotalFloat="19882952713.0">19952507521.0</SharesOut>
            <ReportingCurrency Code="USD">U.S. Dollars</ReportingCurrency>
            <MostRecentExchange Date="2018-07-24">1.0</MostRecentExchange>
    </CoGeneralInfo>
    <TextInfo>
            <Text Type="Business Summary" lastModified="2017-03- 
 06T22:03:17">HSBC Holdings plc (HSBC) is the banking and financial services 
 company. The Company manages its products and services through four     
 businesses: Retail Banking and Wealth Management (RBWM), Commercial Banking 
 (CMB), Global Banking and Markets (GB&amp;M), and Global Private Banking 
 (GPB). It operates across various geographical regions, which include 
 Europe, Asia, Middle East and North Africa, North America and Latin America. 
 RBWM business offers Retail Banking, Wealth Management, Asset Management and 
 Insurance. CMB services include working capital, term loans, payment 
 services and international trade facilitation, among other services, as well 
 as expertise in mergers and acquisitions, and access to financial markets. 
 GB&amp;M supports government, corporate and institutional clients across the 
 world. GPB's products and services include Investment Management, Private 
 Wealth Solutions, and a range of Private Banking services.</Text>
            <Text Type="Financial Summary" lastModified="2018-07- 
20T09:20:11">BRIEF: For the three months ended 31 March 2018, HSBC Holdings 
plc (Hong Kong) interest income increased 10% to $7.46B. Net interest income 
after loan loss provision increased 11% to $7.29B.  Net income applicable to 
common stockholders decreased 1% to $3.09B. Net interest income after loan 
loss provision reflects Asia segment increase of 22% to $3.86B, Net Interest 
Margin, Total -% increase of 2% to 1.67%, Net Interest Spread.</Text>
    </TextInfo>
    <contactInfo lastUpdated="2018-07-20T09:20:26">
            <streetAddress line="1">8 Canada Square</streetAddress>
            <streetAddress line="2"></streetAddress>
            <streetAddress line="3"></streetAddress>
            <city>LONDON</city>
            <state-region></state-region>
            <postalCode>E14 5HQ</postalCode>
            <country code="GBR">United Kingdom</country>
            <contactName></contactName>
            <contactTitle></contactTitle>
            <phone>
                    <phone type="mainphone">
                            <countryPhoneCode>44</countryPhoneCode>
                            <city-areacode>20</city-areacode>
                            <number>79918888</number>
                    </phone>
                    <phone type="mainfax">
                            <countryPhoneCode>44</countryPhoneCode>
                            <city-areacode>20</city-areacode>
                            <number>79924880</number>
                    </phone>
            </phone>
    </contactInfo>
    <webLinks lastUpdated="2016-11-07T05:00:04"><webSite mainCategory="Home 
 Page">http://www.hsbc.com/</webSite><eMail mainCategory="Company Contact/E- 
 mail"></eMail></webLinks>
    <peerInfo lastUpdated="2018-07-20T09:20:26">
            <IndustryInfo>
                    <Industry type="TRBC" order="1" reported="0" 
 code="5510101010" mnem="">Banks - NEC</Industry>
                    <Industry type="NAICS" order="1" reported="0" 
 code="52211" mnem="">Commercial Banking</Industry>
                    <Industry type="NAICS" order="2" reported="0" 
 code="52393" mnem="">Investment Advice</Industry>
                    <Industry type="NAICS" order="3" reported="0" 
 code="52392" mnem="">Portfolio Management</Industry>
                    <Industry type="SIC" order="0" reported="1" code="6035" 
 mnem="">Federal Savings Institutions</Industry>
                    <Industry type="SIC" order="1" reported="0" code="6029" 
 mnem="">Commercial Banks, Nec</Industry>
                    <Industry type="SIC" order="2" reported="0" code="6282" 
 mnem="">Investment Advice</Industry>
            </IndustryInfo>
    </peerInfo>
    <officers>
            <officer rank="1" since="01/01/2013">
                    <firstName>John</firstName>
                    <mI>Michael</mI>
                    <lastName>Flint</lastName>
                    <age>48 </age>
                    <title startYear="2018" startMonth="02" startDay="21" 
 iD1="CEO" abbr1="CEO" iD2="EDR" abbr2="Exec. Dir.">Chief Executive, 
 Executive Director</title>
            </officer>
            <officer rank="2" since="09/24/2010">
                    <firstName>Iain</firstName>
                    <mI>J.</mI>
                    <lastName>Mackay</lastName>
                    <age>56 </age>
                    <title startYear="2010" startMonth="12" startDay="03" 
  iD1="FID" abbr1="Fin. Dir." iD2="EDR" abbr2="Exec. Dir.">Group Finance 
  Director, Executive Director</title>
            </officer>
            <officer rank="3" since="08/01/2015">
                    <firstName>Andy</firstName>
                    <mI></mI>
                    <lastName>Maguire</lastName>
                    <age>51 </age>
                    <title startYear="2015" startMonth="08" startDay="01" 
  iD1="COO" abbr1="COO" iD2="MDR" abbr2="Mgng.Dir.">Group Chief Operating 
  Officer, Group Managing Director</title>
            </officer>
            <officer rank="4" since="11/26/2010">
                    <firstName>Marc</firstName>
                    <mI>M.</mI>
                    <lastName>Moses</lastName>
                    <age>60 </age>
                    <title startYear="2014" startMonth="01" startDay="01" 
  iD1="CRO" abbr1="CRO" iD2="EDR" abbr2="Exec. Dir.">Group Chief Risk 
  Officer, Executive Director</title>
            </officer>
            <officer rank="5" since="NA">
                    <firstName>Elaine</firstName>
                    <mI></mI>
                    <lastName>Arden</lastName>
                    <age>49 </age>
                    <title startYear="NA" startMonth="" startDay="" iD1="MDR" 
 abbr1="Mgng.Dir." iD2="" abbr2="">Managing Director, Group Head of Human 
 Resources</title>
            </officer>
            <officer rank="6" since="01/01/2011">
                    <firstName>Samir</firstName>
                    <mI></mI>
                    <lastName>Assaf</lastName>
                    <age>57 </age>
                    <title startYear="2011" startMonth="01" startDay="01" 
  iD1="MDR" abbr1="Mgng.Dir." iD2="" abbr2="">Group Managing Director, Chief 
  Executive - Global Banking &amp; Markets</title>
            </officer>
            <officer rank="7" since="NA">
                    <firstName>Colin</firstName>
                    <mI></mI>
                    <lastName>Bell</lastName>
                    <age>50 </age>
                    <title startYear="NA" startMonth="" startDay="" iD1="MDR" 
  abbr1="Mgng.Dir." iD2="" abbr2="">Managing Director, Group Head of 
  Financial Crime Risk</title>
            </officer>
            <officer rank="8" since="10/01/2013">
                    <firstName>Peter</firstName>
                    <mI>W.</mI>
                    <lastName>Boyles</lastName>
                    <age>62 </age>
                    <title startYear="2013" startMonth="10" startDay="01" 
   iD1="MDR" abbr1="Mgng.Dir." iD2="" abbr2="">Group Managing Director; Chief 
   Executive of Global Private Banking</title>
            </officer>
            <officer rank="9" since="08/01/2015">
                    <firstName>Patrick</firstName>
                    <mI>J.</mI>
                    <lastName>Burke</lastName>
                    <age>56 </age>
                    <title startYear="2015" startMonth="08" startDay="01" 
  iD1="MDR" abbr1="Mgng.Dir." iD2="" abbr2="">Group Managing Director; 
  President and Chief Executive of HSBC USA</title>
            </officer>
            <officer rank="10" since="08/01/2015">
                    <firstName>Pierre</firstName>
                    <mI></mI>
                    <lastName>Goad</lastName>
                    <age>56 </age>
                    <title startYear="2016" startMonth="" startDay="" 
  iD1="MDR" abbr1="Mgng.Dir." iD2="" abbr2="">Group Managing Director, Group 
  Head of Employee Insight and Communications</title>
            </officer>
    </officers>
    <Ratios PriceCurrency="HKD" ReportingCurrency="USD" 
  ExchangeRate="7.84640" LatestAvailableDate="2017-12-31">
            <Group ID="Price and Volume">
                    <Ratio FieldName="NPRICE" Type="N">75.05000</Ratio>
                    <Ratio FieldName="NHIG" Type="N">86.00000</Ratio>
                    <Ratio FieldName="NLOW" Type="N">71.45000</Ratio>
                    <Ratio FieldName="PDATE" Type="D">2018-07- 
  25T00:00:00</Ratio>
                    <Ratio FieldName="VOL10DAVG" Type="N">12.50806</Ratio>
                    <Ratio FieldName="EV" Type="N">2466752.00000</Ratio>
            </Group>
            <Group ID="Income Statement">
                    <Ratio FieldName="MKTCAP" Type="N">1505191.00000</Ratio>
                    <Ratio FieldName="AREV" Type="N">321663.20000</Ratio>
                    <Ratio FieldName="AEBITD" Type="N">177752.30000</Ratio>
                    <Ratio FieldName="ANIAC" Type="N">86082.85000</Ratio>
            </Group>
            <Group ID="Per share data">
                    <Ratio FieldName="AEPSXCLXOR" Type="N">4.28869</Ratio>
                    <Ratio FieldName="AREVPS" Type="N">27.04842</Ratio>
                    <Ratio FieldName="ABVPS" Type="N">74.66691</Ratio>
                    <Ratio FieldName="ACSHPS" Type="N">108.96660</Ratio>
                    <Ratio FieldName="ACFSHR" Type="N">5.83985</Ratio>
                    <Ratio FieldName="ADIVSHR" Type="N">4.01226</Ratio>
            </Group>
            <Group ID="Other Ratios">
                    <Ratio FieldName="AGROSMGN" Type="N">-99999.99000</Ratio>
                    <Ratio FieldName="AROEPCT" Type="N">6.72498</Ratio>
                    <Ratio FieldName="APR2REV" Type="N">2.77242</Ratio>
                    <Ratio FieldName="APEEXCLXOR" Type="N">17.49954</Ratio>
                    <Ratio FieldName="APRICE2BK" Type="N">1.13825</Ratio>
                    <Ratio FieldName="Employees" Type="N">228899</Ratio>
            </Group>
    </Ratios>
    <ForecastData ConsensusType="Mean" CurFiscalYear="2018" 
   CurFiscalYearEndMonth="12" CurInterimEndCalYear="2018" 
   CurInterimEndMonth="3" EarningsBasis="PRX">
            <Ratio FieldName="ConsRecom" Type="N">
                    <Value PeriodType="CURR">1.9167</Value>
            </Ratio>
            <Ratio FieldName="TargetPrice" Type="N">
                    <Value PeriodType="CURR">86.00753</Value>
            </Ratio>
            <Ratio FieldName="ProjLTGrowthRate" Type="N">
                    <Value PeriodType="CURR">6.9100</Value>
            </Ratio>
            <Ratio FieldName="ProjPE" Type="N">
                    <Value PeriodType="CURR">13.07573</Value>
            </Ratio>
            <Ratio FieldName="ProjSales" Type="N">
                    <Value PeriodType="CURR">433073.04033</Value>
            </Ratio>
            <Ratio FieldName="ProjSalesQ" Type="N">
                    <Value PeriodType="CURR">276091.27680</Value>
            </Ratio>
            <Ratio FieldName="ProjEPS" Type="N">
                    <Value PeriodType="CURR">5.73964</Value>
            </Ratio>
            <Ratio FieldName="ProjEPSQ" Type="N">
                    <Value PeriodType="CURR">1.64774</Value>
            </Ratio>
            <Ratio FieldName="ProjProfit" Type="N">
                    <Value PeriodType="CURR">168752.58051</Value>
            </Ratio>
            <Ratio FieldName="ProjDPS" Type="N">
                    <Value PeriodType="CURR">4.03148</Value>
            </Ratio>
    </ForecastData>
</ReportSnapshot>'''


import lxml.etree

soup = lxml.etree.fromstring(data)

for item in soup.xpath('//IssueID'):
    print(item.attrib['Type'], ':', item.text)
```

Result:

```
Name : Ordinary Shares
Ticker : 5
CUSIP : G4634U169
ISIN : GB0005405286
RIC : 0005.HK
SEDOL : 6158163
DisplayRIC : 0005.HK
InstrumentPI : 312270
QuotePI : 1049324
```

Comment: it does work. when 
soup = lxml.etree.fromstring(data.encode('ascii'))
thank you very much furas

Comment: What does QuotePI and InstrumentPI refer to?

Comment: @Yana `QuotePI` and `InstrumentPI` are data in XML - ie. `<IssueID Type="QuotePI">1049324</IssueID>` - but I don't know what they means and I don't care what that means. I only wrote code to work with XML. You should ask OP (author of question - author of Original Post) what it means.